# encountering a square or null or ? mark in retrieving utf-8 characters from mysql database in java

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, byte

There is no problem when I try to insert this symbol "ñÑ" in the mysql database. However, when I try to retrieve the same data the symbol or character that was selected by the query would appear as null value or something like a `?` or a square.

Please help me with these I have been troubled many weeks by these problems. I just cannot understand anymore. I have written the code in java.

Comment: i would like to have an out is like this : Ñ

Answer (score 0):

The "�" is the [replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character), used when something processing characters can't display or otherwise handle a character. A box is sometimes used for the same purpose, or indicates that the font being used doesn't have a glyph for some character.

To resolve this, check that the [character sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html) being used for the various components, such as the column and connection, are correct.

See also: "[Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)"

Comment: i have tried that but same results.. i would like to get Ñ from a blob char type in my database